# How can I rotate a plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, rotation

I want to rotate the plot `scatterplot(rxSig)` (shown below) 8 degrees, for example.
(the group of the red dots in the photo)
it's not looks like a regular plot and I didn't found a relevant information for that.

**Expected Result:** (with rotation)
[image: expected result]

**Plot without rotation:**
[image: plot without rotation]

```
R = 1000.0;
freq = 28*1e9;
T = 20.0;
lwd = 0.5;
F = fogpl(R,freq,T,lwd);
P = 101300.0;
W = 7.5;
G = gaspl(R,freq,T,P,W);
RR=[0.75,1.75,2.5,3];

for irr=1:length(RR)
    R = rainpl(10000,freq,RR(irr));
    L=R+F+G;
end

M = 64;                % Modulation order
k = log2(M);            % Bits per symbol
EbNoVec = (0:25)';      % Eb/No values (dB)
numSymPerFrame = 1000;



for n = 1:length(EbNoVec)
% Convert Eb/No to SNR
    snrdB = EbNoVec(n) + 10*log10(k)-L(1);
    % Reset the error and bit counters
    numErrs = 0;
    numBits = 0;

    while numErrs < 200 && numBits < 1e8

         % Generate binary data and convert to symbols
         dataIn = randi([0 1],numSymPerFrame,k);
         dataSym = bi2de(dataIn);

         % QAM modulate using 'Gray' symbol mapping
         txSig = qammod(dataSym,M);

         % Pass through AWGN channel
         rxSig = awgn(txSig,snrdB,'measured');

         % Demodulate the noisy signal
         rxSym = qamdemod(rxSig,M);
         % Convert received symbols to bits
         dataOut = de2bi(rxSym,k);

         % Calculate the number of bit errors
        nErrors = biterr(dataIn,dataOut);


        % Increment the error and bit counters
        numErrs = numErrs + nErrors;
        numBits = numBits + numSymPerFrame*k;
    end

    % Estimate the BER
    berEst(n) = numErrs/numBits;
end

berTheory = berawgn(EbNoVec,'qam',M);

semilogy(EbNoVec,berEst,'*')
hold on
semilogy(EbNoVec,berTheory)
grid
legend('Estimated BER with our attenuation function','Theoretical Matlab BER')
xlabel('Eb/No (dB)')
ylabel('Bit Error Rate')
scatterplot(rxSig)
```

Comment: The code you posted does not involve `scatterplot` at all and does not reproduce the "plot without rotation". Are you looking for rotating a plot data in general?

Comment: If it is simple rotation of data points, perhaps you can obtain the plot data using [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100921-how-do-i-extract-data-points-from-a-plot). Then you can apply a rotation matrix for this data using [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/323483-how-to-rotate-points-on-2d-coordinate-systems). [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

Comment: the `scatterplot ` apear at the bottom line..
i'm looking to rotate the current plot, is there any difference?

Comment: in addition, i want a visual rotation of chosen angle (not only 90 degree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combined both my suggestions to create the following code.

```
% Extract data points from current figure
h = findobj(gca,'Type','line');
x_org=get(h,'Xdata');
y_org=get(h,'Ydata');
points = [x_org; y_org]';

% to rotate 8 degree counterclockwise    
theta = 8;
% Rotation matrix
R = [cosd(theta) -sind(theta); sind(theta) cosd(theta)];

% Rotate points
points_rot = R*points';
figure(3)
plot(points_rot(1,:), points_rot(2,:), '.');
```

Adding this to the end of your code results in the following figure:
[image]